# Call method of an controller in another controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs, events, methods, controller, broadcast

I try to call an method of civilitiyController in CustomerController. So, with my search I have found the event's manager to call method but I don't success to  return the result from CivilityController to CustomerController.

I already tried this:

1/
    civilitiesController :

```
$scope.$on("getListCivilities", function(event, args){
     $scope.civilities = getCivilitiesList();
});

customersController :

$scope.$broadcast("getListCivilities");
console.dir($scope.civilities) // after run civilities = undefined
```

2/CivilitiesController:

```
$scope.$on("getListCivilities" , function(event, args){
     var list = getCivilitiesList();
     return list;
});
```

CustomersController :

```
$scope.civilities = $scope.$broadcast("getListCivilities");
console.dir($scope.civilities); //display var of broadcast
```

3/ Edit:
After first answer, I tried this :

civilities controller :

```
 function getCivilitiesList()
    {
        var reqGetCivilities = $http({ url: 'api/Civilities/Get' });
        reqGetCivilities.success(function(data){
            $scope.civilities = data;
            $scope.$broadcast("getListCivilities", { list: $scope.civilities });
            return data;
        });
    }
    getCivilitiesList();
```

customersController :

```
function test()
    {
        $scope.$on("getListCivilities", function (event, args) {
            $scope.civilities = args.list;
            console.log('test0');
            console.dir($scope.civilities);
        });
    }

    test();
```

$scope.$on is never executed and I don't see why.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: change $scope.$broadcast this to $rootScope.$broadcast and inject rootscpope to your civilities controller

Comment: I already tested and it doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure that is the correct way to declare a controller and use it

Comment: I given two methods of my controllers. But it's not my entire controllers. I will post my entire civilitiesController but customerController it's too much long and the major part of this controller it not interresting for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hHTPOGWxsUKsGgpGGnYo?p=preview)

```
app.controller('Controller1', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.$on('ValueUpdated', function(event, args) {
    $scope.name = args.currentValue;
  });
});

app.controller('Controller2', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  $scope.myData = "type here";
  $scope.broadCast = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('ValueUpdated', {
      currentValue: $scope.myData
    });
  }
```

I used broadcast, but you can do this with services and watchers too.

Comment: When I see your example I think that I do an error. If I want send my civilities list to the customerController I shouldn't put the $broadcast method in my civilitiesController and the $on method in the CustomersController ?

Comment: yes, think controller2 as your civilitiesController and controller1 as your customerController. so controller2 broadcasts controller1 acts

Comment: I don't know if you see my edit. But I tried to do it like you but my $on is not called and I don't know solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess below should work :

```
function CivilitiesController($scope) 
{
  $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, args) {});
  // another controller or even directive
}

function CustomersController($scope) 
{
  $scope.$emit('someEvent', args);
}
```

JSFiddle (for more details) : http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/moo89kaw/

Answer (score 0):

Ahmet Zeytindalı, this is my entire CivilitiesController :

```
(function () {
'use strict';
'use strict';

angular
    .module('LSapp')
    .controller('CivilitiesCtrl', CivilitiesCtrl)

CivilitiesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope'];

function CivilitiesCtrl($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
    function getCivilitiesList()
    {
        var reqGetCivilities = $http({ url: 'api/Civilities/Get' });
        reqGetCivilities.success(function(data){
            $scope.civilities = data;
        });
    }
    getCivilitiesList();

    function getList()
    {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("getListCivilities", { list: $scope.civilities });
    }
    getList();
}
```

})();

And the method to retreive list:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('LSapp')
    .controller('CustomersCtrl', CustomersCtrl)

CustomersCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$modal', '$window', '$compile','$cookies', '$state','locker','$q','$timeout', '$rootScope'];

function CustomersCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $modal, $window, $compile, $cookies, $state, locker, $q, $timeout) {
     //some code
 function test()
    {
        $scope.$on("getListCivilities", function (event, args) {
            $scope.civilities = args.list;
            console.log('$on args : ');
            console.dir(args);
        });
    }
    test();

}
```

});

The method $on doesn't run and if I put console.log($scope.civilities) after the method, the result is always undefined.

Comment: delete whole getlist function and delete getList(); too. Then move $rootScope.$broadcast inside of reqGetCivilities.success(function(data){

Comment: I already tested it and it doesn't work. It's for that I created a method to call broadcast. But I think that my problem come from CustomerController with $on method and not from civilityController. I'm not sure because I don't know how to test the value of broadcast but when I put a console.log() in broadcast method it's display and not in my $on method.

Comment: I managed to works the communication between controllers. It's realy an little error in fact, I forgot to instanciate my CivilityControlller. Thanks for your help, it was really usefull to better understand the communication between controller.